# Using cat output in osascript in terminal

Tags: terminal

I want to display a notification using osascript in terminal, but the text I want to display is stored in a text file. How can I display that text in the notification?

Answer (score 2):

Basically you need to read the file content into a variable first. There are several ways to do this, one is

```
text=$(< TEXTFILE)
osascript ... "$text"
```

Comment: so there's no way to do it in a one-liner?

Comment: Sure, just replace the variable with the `$(...)` construct

Answer (score 2):

In the Bash shell, you can read in the text of the file using `cat` and shove it into a substitution.

Something like:

`osascript -e "display notification \"$(cat /tmp/foo.txt)\" with title \"hello\""`

(Obviously put something in `/tmp/foo.txt` first, like `echo "Hello world" > /tmp/foo.txt`)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the complete soloution to my initial question I posted about:

```
set listOfCommand to (read POSIX file "path-to/command.txt")
  tell application "Terminal"
    do script listOfCommand
    delay 1
    quit
  end tell
set listOfShows to (read POSIX file "path-to/dump.txt")
 tell application "Safari"
    display notification listOfShows with title "Downloads:"
 end tell
```